# I will be free any time of the day

Tags: phrase-usage, time

I'm setting up a meeting for my job application, and I can't get my head around this.

> To answer your question, I will be available next week on Wednesday and Thursday, that is the 9 and 10 June. The week after, I'm available on Monday, Tuesday and Friday, that is the 14, 15 and 18 June. I will be free any time of the day.

I'm trying to say that I do not care at which time the meeting takes place, but I'm trying to say it politely, and I'm not sure if saying "free any time of the day(s)?" is formal enough for an e-mail to my employer.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing impolite in your sentence. You could potentially make the paragraph slightly shorter; here were some ideas I came up with (edits are in **bold**):

> To answer your question, I will be available **all day next Wednesday and Thursday as well as all day the following** Monday, Tuesday, and Friday.
>
> To answer your question, I will be available **all day on June 9 and 10 as well as all day on June** 14, 15, and 18.

These are just my thoughts, however. Some may find them more difficult to understand than your phrasing.